# C#: Unity3D and NAudio EnumerateAudioEndPoints throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio

I'm trying to use the NAudio library in a Unity3D project.  When calling MMDeviceEnumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints, a NullReferenceException is thrown.  This does not occur in a Visual Studio project targeting .NET 2.0.  The enumerator itself is not null.  That method wraps a call to IMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints, which is what's directly throwing this exception (I moved a bunch of code from NAudio into my Unity3D project).

The only real difference here is that it's running inside a Unity3D game, rather than a standard Visual Studio application.  What could be causing this?  Please help.

**Update:**

My code that throws (second line):

```
MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDeviceCollection collection = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.All);
```

NAudio code that throws (second line of method):

```
public MMDeviceCollection EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow dataFlow, DeviceState dwStateMask)
{
    IMMDeviceCollection result;
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(_realEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(dataFlow, dwStateMask, out result));
    return new MMDeviceCollection(result);
}
```

**Update x2:**

In the constructor for MMDeviceEnumerator in NAudio:

```
_realEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject() as IMMDeviceEnumerator;
```

The new com object is not null, but when casting, it becomes null.  Again, this works in a Visual Studio project, but not Unity3D.  Here's the definitions of each (from the NAudio source):

```
[ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
class MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject
{
}
```

and

```
[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    int EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow dataFlow, DeviceState stateMask,
        out IMMDeviceCollection devices);

    int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow dataFlow, Role role, out IMMDevice endpoint);

    int GetDevice(string id, out IMMDevice deviceName);

    int RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient client);

    int UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient client);
}
```

I can post the other objects in there if necessary.  What I'm missing is probably the core "why" something between Unity3D (also targeting .NET 2.0) and Visual Studio would change.

Comment: Can you show the code around the line the exception occurs on? Or maybe a limited example showing the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `_realEnumerator`?

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot.  The newed up MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject is not null, but casting it results in a null.  I'm still kind of lost though.

Comment: Did you cast it using `as`? If you did then if the cast is invalid then the resulting object will contain `null`. Either repurpose this question with detail, *or* ask another question (after closing or deleting this one of course).

Comment: I updated with more details.  Thanks again.

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/142183/typeloadexception-when-taking-naudioall-as-referen.html)?